# Count the amount of times '$' shows up in a string (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, int

I was wondering if there was an easy method to find the amount of times a character such as '$' shows up in a string in the language objective-c.

The real world example I am using is a string that would look like:

```
542$764$231$DataEntry
```

What I need to do is first:

1) count the amount of times the '$' shows up to know what tier the DataEntry is in my database (my database structure is one I made up)

2) then I need to get all of the numbers, as they are index numbers. The numbers need to be stored in a NSArray. And I will loop through them all getting the different indexes. I'm not going to explain how my database structure works as that isn't relevant.

Basically from that NSString, I need, the amount of times '$' shows up. And all of the numbers in between the dollar signs. This would be a breeze to do in PHP, but I was curious to see how I could go about this in Objective-C.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[@"542$764$231$DataEntry" componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"] count]-1
```

Comment: thanks! Any idea on how I could get the numbers in between the $?

Comment: Just leave out the count invocation: `NSArray *components = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"];`

Comment: remove 1st and last object from components array.

Answer (score 1):

The `componentsSeparatedByString` suggested by @Parag Bafna and @J Shapiro or `NSRegularExpression` e.g.:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSError *error = NULL;
        NSString *searchText = @"542$764$231$DataEntry";
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\d{3})\\$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
        NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:searchText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length]) ];

        printf("match count = %ld\n",numberOfMatches);
        [regex enumerateMatchesInString:searchText 
                                options:0 
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0,[searchText length]) 
                             usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
            NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
            printf("match = %s\n",[[searchText substringWithRange:range] UTF8String]);
        }];     
    }
}
```

The `componentsSeparatedByString` is probably the preferred approach and much more performant where the pattern has simple repeating delimiters; but I included this approach for completeness sake.

Comment: thank you for the regex approach! it is very informational! I will definitely be keeping this in mind if things get complex!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    NSMutableArray* substrings=[NSMutableArray new];
    // This will contain all the substrings
    NSMutableArray* numbers=[NSMutableArray new];
    // This will contain all the numbers
    NSNumberFormatter* formatter=[NSNumberFormatter new];
    // The formatter will scan all the strings and estabilish if they're
    // valid numbers, if so it will produce a NSNumber object
    [formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSString* entry= @"542$764$231$DataEntry";
    NSUInteger count=0,last=0;
    // count will contain the number of '$' characters found
    NSRange range=NSMakeRange(0, entry.length);
    // range is the range where to check
    do
    {
        range= [entry rangeOfString: @"$" options: NSLiteralSearch range: range];
        // Check for a substring
        if(range.location!=NSNotFound)
        {
            // If there's not a further substring range.location will be NSNotFound
            NSRange substringRange= NSMakeRange(last, range.location-last);
            // Get the range of the substring
            NSString* substring=[entry substringWithRange: substringRange];
            [substrings addObject: substring];
            // Get the substring and add it to the substrings mutable array
            last=range.location+1;
            range= NSMakeRange(range.location+range.length, entry.length-range.length-range.location);
            // Calculate the new range where to check for the next substring
            count++;
            // Increase the count
        }
    }while( range.location!=NSNotFound);
    // Now count contains the number of '$' characters found, and substrings
    // contains all the substrings separated by '$'
    for(NSString* substring in substrings)
    {
        // Check all the substrings found
        NSNumber* number;
        if([formatter getObjectValue: &number forString: substring range: nil error: nil])
        {
            // If the substring is a valid number, the method returns YES and we go
            // inside this scope, so we can add the number to the numbers array
            [numbers addObject: number];
        }
    }
    // Now numbers contains all the numbers found
```